# Why do we need to pass the program path along with the core file to the debugger?

Tags: debugging, gdb, coredump, dbx

Is it relevant that the program is exactly the same build as the one which crashed to generate the core file?

```
dbx <program path> <core path>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program contains the symbol table, which is used to translate locations in the core dump to program statements and variable names. If you use a different build, these locations usually will have changed, so many, perhaps most, symbolic references won't work correctly when debugging.